# packrat - move environment from one project to another

Tags: r, packrat

I am using `packrat` in one of my R-studio project, call it project A. I also created brand new project (call it B), I would like to take environment of project A and move it to project B. Can I just copy packrat folder from one project to another.

Comment: Just a note that `packrat` is no longer being developed, and `renv` is its replacement.